# How to Move Already Written and working project With No Frameworks to Kohana?

Tags: frameworks, kohana, move

I'm curious if it is possible to move the written and fully working project to Kohana step-by-step. I mean if it is possible to replace page by page. So the project will move consequently from 100% of non-framework code to 100% of Kohana code, page by page.
The project uses php/js/css/html, MySQL and Apache.
The project is huge (with a guest and member areas).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Kohana, but I'm quite familiar in other PHP framework (Yii). My guess is that it is NOT possible. Or to put it in other way: everything is possible (except opening an umbrella in your ass! :), but taking time (and money) into account, it is not worth doing so.

Most professional frameworks are complete opposite to "pure PHP" code in extremely many areas. Code is separated most times (MVC = model-view-controller design pattern) and uses mostly framework classes or code. I would even risk to say that writing an application in some pro framework means using only 10-20% of pure PHP code and doing rest 80-90% purely on framework classes, extensions, controllers etc.

In other words: porting a "pure PHP" application into framework code would mean writing that application from scratch. I'm not sure, if you would be able to copy-paste more than 5-10% of your source code?

Comment: If you design your application correctly, you'll be isolating your business code from your "framework" code. You shouldn't need to rely on any delivery mechanism (which is what a framework normally is) for your use cases and core business logic.

Comment: I agree with you. But this IMHO still doesn't answer if porting pure PHP application to any framework is possible or not (profitable or not)? :]

Comment: You can port anything to anything else. You might not use any of the original code, but you can port functionality fairly easily. If you design your architecture like I describe above, when you decide to delivery over a different "thing", you can easily do that as well.